# IPython redirects to command window after attempted python version update

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, ipython

I am trying to learn something about GUI and game programming, so I was wanting to install Pygame. I was reading through how to install it, and I was recommended to make sure I had the latest version of either Python 3.3.x or 2.7.x installed in order to be most compatible. I had an earlier version of 2.7.x installed, so I attempted to update my installation. I downloaded and installed (went through the whole installation process) for the new version of 2.7.x, though I didn't uninstall anything (I don't even know how to uninstall Python as it doesn't show up in programs and features). Now, when I try to open IPython, I get redirected to the Windows Command Line rather than the interactive Python window. I need the interactive Python for work and school, so how do I regain functionality to that.

I looked in the folder containing all my Python installation data, and I found that there is no Ipython.exe file, but rather that the source of my IPython installation seems to be a .bat file instead. Is this correct? For being a computer science major I'm really bad at all this stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could just reinstall ipython if your previous installation got messed up - http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html#windows

Comment: How do I then reinstall IPython?